# How to fix "a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition"

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to create a function that would take a name(string) that has been input by a user and compare it with a string within a custom data type/structure to verify that the name that the user has input exists in the memory.

The custom data type is set to be global and is as follows:

```
// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];
```

The names of the different candidates are stored in the array `candidates` via a command line argument.

After that the user is prompted to vote for a candidate by inserting the name of a candiate using:
`string name = get_string("Vote: ");`

which is then taken to this function to verify whether the candidate's name exists or not.

Here is the function:

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    int i;
    string cn = candidates[i].name;
    for (i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        int strcmp(cn, name);
    }

    return strcmp;
}
```

However, I am not sure what the error means:

```
a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
        int strcmp(cn, name);
                   ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, you can start by looking at the [man page](https://manpages.org/strcmp) for the `strcmp` function. That's nowhere near correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strcmp()` compares two strings character by character.

If the strings are equal, the function returns `0`.

A simple way to use `strcmp`:

```
int returnValue = strcmp(cn, name);
if (returnValue == 0) {
    // string matched, so this name exists
}
```

Please check below 2 links to learn more about `strcmp()`

- [C strcmp()](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp)
- [strcmp() in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcmp-in-c-cpp/)

Another mistake to mention, you tried to access the ith candidate's name from outside the loop.

You need to do it from inside.

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    string cn = candidates[i].name;
}
```